# Not able to add new menu items in WordPress 4.1

Tags: wordpress

I am building a Word Press site with a large custom menu structure (around 100 items). I have successfully added some menu items, but now not able to add more menu items.
I get no error messages or any indication that something went wrong.

After searching around, I have discovered a number of discussion threads that suggest this could be a max_input_vars issue. 
I have tried any/all suggestions from these threads, and no luck. I noticed that a number of other people in these threads also seem to have hit a wall.

Any thoughts on how to proceed? Any help appreciated!

Comment: without any error its hard to detect the exact problem, please visit to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and re-submit your question there.

Comment: You could also try adding this to your .htaccess file: (do one or the other)
php_value max_input_vars 5000

Answer (score 0):

The most probably is that your theme or one of your plugin is causing some issue. I recommend you to do this task for debugging the issue:

- First off all make sure to have WP_DEBUG turn on in your wp-config.php file: Debugging in WordPress. If you see any error, fix it. If no error, continue to the next task.
- Activate the default WordPress theme Twenty Fifteen and try to add and image to a post again, if it doesn't work, it means that your theme is not the problem. Continue to the next task.
- Deactivate all your plugin, one by one, and try to add an image to a post after each plugin deactivation. If after deactivating all the plugins the error continues... the next task.
- If nothing works, I will re-install WordPress. You can keep your themes, plugins and media by keeping the wp-content folder. Just delete wp-admin, wp-include and all the files, download a new version of WordPress and upload again this files.